# How to detect a rectangle in a 3D world?

Tags: java, algorithm, detection, rectangles

I have a set of points. Each point has three coordinates : X, Y and Z. I want to be able to detect the four points **that are the corners** of a rectangle (! not a cube !) :

1. All these rectangle's points can have the same Z (thus, the rectangle is not drawn in depth and only X and Y change)
2. All these rectangle's points can have the same Y (thus, the rectangle is drawn in depth and only X and Z change)
3. etc.
4. Especially, all these rectangle's points can have X, Y and Z that change (i.e. : the rectangle is drawn in "diagonal").

*REMEMBER* : "all these rectangle's points" = "the four rectangle's corners".

---

## My solution (works only in a 2D world)

I wrote an algorithm that detects the four rectangle's corner, but for the moment it works only with points that have 2 coordinates (X and Y).

The algorithm is :

1. I take a point `A` of the set and I assume it is a corner
2. I take the next point, `B`, of the set (if X and Y are different from `A`'s ones) and I assume it is the diagonal corner
3. I take the next next point, `C`, and check if its X or Y is the same of `A`'s or `B`'s respective X or Y : if yes, I decide that it's the third corner. I do this again for the fourth corner.

**That's the gist. Now, the source code (with some explanations at the end).**

```
    List<Point> returned_rectangle = new ArrayList<>();
    List<StorableData> sorted_abscissa_aligned_points = this.preTreatment();

    Point current_point_not_delete, neighbour_cupple_of_current_point, absc, ord, other_point;
    for(StorableData current_store_data : sorted_abscissa_aligned_points) { // Diagonal's points

        current_point_not_delete = (Point) current_store_data;

        for (StorableData neighbour_storable_data_of_current_cupple : sorted_abscissa_aligned_points) { // Diagonal's points
        if(neighbour_storable_data_of_current_cupple == null) {
        continue;
        }

        neighbour_cupple_of_current_point = (Point) neighbour_storable_data_of_current_cupple;

        if(Math.abs(neighbour_cupple_of_current_point.getNumber(0) - current_point_not_delete.getNumber(0)) <= PRECISION_DIAGONAL
        || Math.abs(neighbour_cupple_of_current_point.getNumber(1) - current_point_not_delete.getNumber(1)) <= PRECISION_DIAGONAL) {
          continue;
        }


        absc = null;
        ord = null;

        for(StorableData other_point_storable_data : sorted_abscissa_aligned_points) { // Abs and ord rectangle's points
            other_point = (Point) other_point_storable_data;
            if(other_point == null) {
            continue;
            }

            if(Math.abs(other_point.getNumber(0) - current_point_not_delete.getNumber(0)) <= PRECISION
            && Math.abs(other_point.getNumber(1) - neighbour_cupple_of_current_point.getNumber(1)) <= PRECISION) {

                absc = other_point;

            } else if(Math.abs(other_point.getNumber(0) - neighbour_cupple_of_current_point.getNumber(0)) <= PRECISION
            && Math.abs(other_point.getNumber(1) - current_point_not_delete.getNumber(1)) <= PRECISION) {

                ord = other_point;

            }

            if(absc != null && ord != null) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(absc != null && ord != null) {
                returned_rectangle.add(absc);
                returned_rectangle.add(current_point_not_delete);
                returned_rectangle.add(ord);
                returned_rectangle.add(neighbour_cupple_of_current_point);
                return returned_rectangle;
        }

        }

        sorted_abscissa_aligned_points.set(sorted_abscissa_aligned_points.indexOf(current_point_not_delete), null);
    }
```

The detection is really done in the third `for` (counted from the top of the code). `getNumber(0)` means "reads the X coordinate", `getNumber(1)` the Y one, 2 : Z.

---

## My question

As you understood, my algorithm works well if a rectangle is drawn in X and Y coordinates, but doesn't take account of the depth (Z).

**How could I extend it ?** Maybe I will have to use `cos` and other things like that.

Comment: Rectangles are two-dimensional. Do you mean [cuboid](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid)?

Comment: You wish to detect this in actual 3D coordinates and not for projections in a 2D plane, yes? @Michael The asker means to detect for a given set of points which sets of 4 constitute a rectangle in space. Which means that the 4 points must be coplanar (a plane can be made that contains all 4) and the points can be connected in pairs by line segments so that the adjacent segments form angles of 90°. This is perfectly possible in a 3D space.

Comment: Mmmh. I want to detect (only) one face of a cuboid, the other 5 faces not existing. That's why I said that I want to detect a rectangle : his four corners have a Z coordinate.

Comment: Let me see if I can understand you. If you want't to detect a rectangle in a 3d world, you need to identify the first corner, from there, if you have all the coordinates ordered, check distances between them and based on that, mark it as a valid rectangle. Is something like this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

First a little remark. I believe your current algorithm is only going to work for the detection of rectangles in a 2D space where the sides are parallel/perpendicular to the x/y axis. In other words, a rectangle that has been "rotated" (diagonal, as you described it) is not going to be detected.

I suggest a different algorithm that would work in 2D and 3D. Here's a rough draft of the code:

```
List<Point> points;
// Assign list ...

// Iterate for first point...
for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 3; ++i) {
    // Second point...
    for (int j = i + 1; j < points.size() - 2; ++j) {
        // Third point...
        for (int k = j + 1; k < points.size() - 1; ++k) {
            // Get the three points
            Point p1 = points.get(i);
            Point p2 = points.get(j);
            Point p3 = points.get(k);
            // Array for corner point and its two adjacent points if there's a 90° angle
            Point[] angle;
            if ((angle = checkRightAngle(p1, p2, p3)) != null) {
                // Calculate which point would form a rectangle with the given 3 points
                Point remainingCorner = translate(angle[0], angle[1], angle[2]);
                // Check the remaining points and see if any match the remaining corver
                for (int l = k + 1; l < points.size(); ++l) {
                    Point p4 = points.get(l);
                    if (distanceWithinPrecision(remainingCorner, p4) {
                        // p1, p2, p3 and p4 form a rectangle; use the result as needed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Point[] checkRightAngle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    // For each of the three points, check if it forms a 90° angle with the other two points
    // If such a point is found, return an array with the corner point in the first index 
    // and the remaining to points in the other indexes
    // If no such point is found, return null
}

Point translate(Point source, Point other1, Point other2) {
    // Calculate the vectors from source to other1 and source to other2
    // Create a new Point that has the coordinates resulting from translating source by
    // the two vectors and return it
}
```

Let's go through this for a bit. The three loops will result in going through every combination of three points minus the last one (will be checked later) without repeating a set of points. The three points in the combination are checked for whether they form a right angle.

Method `checkRightAngle` should check for each of the 3 points given to it whether it forms a 90° angle with the other two. If there's no 90° angle it just returns null. If there is such a 90° angle, it should return a Point array with as first element the Point that sits at the 90° angle and as second and third elements the other two Points (their order doesn't matter). For calculating the angle between two intersecting line segments in 3 dimensions you should easily find formulas online. Note that there's an opportunity for a little optimization here. Suppose that you've checked the angle for 2 of the points as a corner and neither was 90°, you can then just check if their sum was 90°; in a triangle the sum of all three corner angles is 180° so if two corners have a **sum** of 90° as angles, the remaining one must be 90° by definition. So you'd need to check two angles at most.

If the three points form a right angle, method `translate` is then used to determine what the remaining point for forming a rectangle should be. The way you do this is by taking the point that is the corner of the 90° angle (angle[0] array element), creating two vectors using the remaining two points (angle[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld5Hf.png) and angle[2]) and creating a new Point that is the translation of the corner point by those two vectors.

This works by the observation that if you take any point, the two points that would result from separate translations by two vectors and the one point that would result from translation by both vectors, the points will form a parallelogram.

[image: vector translations in parallelogram]

In our case, the two vectors were already established to be perpendicular (90° angle) so the result will be a rectangle.

Actually, all you need to do is establish the vector between the corner point and one of the non-corner points, and add that to the other corner point. So in the above example, suppose that p1 has coordinates (x1, y1, z2), p2 has coordinates (x2, y2, z2) and p3 has coordinates (x3, y3, z3). The vector from p1 to p2 is then (x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1). You add that to (x3, y3, z3), yielding (x2 - x1 + x3, y2 - y1 + y3, z2 - z1 + z3). This yields your remaining rectangle point.

The final thing to do then is calculate whether the distance between this required 4th point and any of the remaining points from your input is lower than some threshold, to conclude that this remaining point forms a rectangle with the other three.